# Wordpress with my design

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have own design for a website to be developed with wordpress, but I need to know if this program allows me to use my own and not their prefabricated templates. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any template writen to work with wordpress. You just need a webdeveloper who will transform a project to a working template :)